# utf-8 to string gets extra added characters

Tags: android, arrays, string, utf-8, textview

IN ANDROID

When I am getting an utf-8 result from a server and I take the output of the server to a string what happens is I get extra escape characters added to the string.

In code what happens is

```
String unicodeMessage =  "\u09aa\u09cd\u09b0\u099c\"; //this is how I want it

String unicodeMessage = "\\u09aa\\u09cd\\u09b0\\u099c\\"; // this is what happens
```

I tried doing the bytes method mentioned in the previous posts yet it doesn't work

```
byte[] bytes = unicodeMessage.getBytes("UTF-8");
answer = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

I'm getting the same output as the input string.

Is there a way I can remove the escape characters added?

```
 String bengali = "\\u09aa\\u09cd\\u09b0\\u099c\\u099c"; //this is the input 

//\u09aa\u09cd\u09b0\u099c\u099c is the output i get when i print bengali and use replace("\\\\","\\"); 

 //প্রজজ is the expected output when input = "\u09aa\u09cd\u09b0\u099c\u099c"

 // u09aau09cdu09b0u099cu099c output when i use replace("\\","")
```

Comment: Try this **unicodeMessage  = unicodeMessage.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\");**

Comment: hey the app is crashing when is use the above code thanks @AliAhmed

Comment: Post your Logcat. what is error?

Comment: String bengali = "\\u09aa\\u09cd\\u09b0\\u099c\\u099c";
        y = bengali.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\");

        xxx.setText(y);  //got an array out of bounds exception: 1  on this@AliAhmed

Comment: have you tried just **replace** instead of **replaceAll**?

Comment: giving the same output as input not working as expected @AliAhmed

Comment: unicodeMessage = unicodeMessage.replace("\\\\","\\");
I have tested it.. working for me

Comment: no its not working if its working you should get bengali characters as output as they are the utf-8 characters of bengali letter plz look into it thanks @AliAhmed

Comment: Please understand why getBytes and new String cancel out each other (when given the same character encoding).

Comment: Could you ask the service to give you UTF-8 straight up? That would be much easier and more common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have in a single unicode string like `\u09aa` is the hex value of the character (`09aa` = `2474` in decimal) escaped with `\u`. So you need to parse these values and convert them to a real unicode character. Below is a function to do so:

```
public static String getRealUnicodeString(String unicodeInput) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]+)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(unicodeInput);
    while (m.find()) {
        String unicodeChar = m.group(1);
        unicodeInput = unicodeInput.replaceAll("\\\\u" + unicodeChar, String.valueOf((char) Integer.parseInt(unicodeChar, 16)));
    }
    return unicodeInput;
}
```

And then use it:

```
System.out.println(getRealUnicodeString("\\u09aa\\u09cd\\u09b0\\u099c\\u099c \n StackoveFlow"));
```

Comment: its giving me the same output the code isn't working

Comment: @Srijay if you need to remove one escape character this is the way to do it. In case you need 2 escape characters removed try passing `""` as the second parameter. Otherwise let me know what you need exactly so I can help you.

Comment: String bengali = "\\u09aa\\u09cd\\u09b0\\u099c\\u099c"; //this is the input //\u09aa\u09cd\u09b0\u099c\u099c is the output i get when i print  bengali //প্রজজ is the expected output // u09aau09cdu09b0u099cu099c is the output i'm getting plz look into it thanks

Comment: hey your code works only if there are bengali letters or unicode letter but doesn't work if it is a mixture of bengali letters and english like"\\u09aa\\u09cd\\u09b0\\u099c\\u099c  \n stackoveflow" thanks can you suggest anything about what can i do

Comment: Edited, hope it helps.

Comment: getting number format exception for input " \\u20181345678945678" any ideas how to overcome this.

Comment: `20181345678945678` is not a unicode character value. If you need to limit the unicode hex characters length, you can specify a range instead of `+` in the regex like `{0,8}` which limits the length to maximum of 8 hex characters. So the `\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]+)` will be replaced with `\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{0,8})`